# $(document).Ready() loads Flexigrid, but not when called again by other function outside $(document).Ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, flexigrid

I have a function called "loadTimeTrackersGrid()", which loads a flexigrid. 
The setup looks like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var editTrackerID = 0;
        loadTimeTrackersGrid();
)};
```

The beginning of the function looks like this :

```
function loadTimeTrackersGrid(caseStatus) {
        var url = 'Utilities/DataViewHandlers/ViewTimeTrackers.ashx?CaseFileID=' + $('#hidCaseFile').val();

        if ($('#hidTaskID').val() !== "")
            url += '&TaskID=' + $('#hidTaskID').val();

        if (caseStatus == "NI") {
            url += '&NonInvoiced=1';
        }

        $('#viewTimeTrackersGrid').flexigrid({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'get',
```

As you can see it calls another page which contains a stored procedure which returns a set of rows and a jsonwriter then puts the returned columns into the flexigrid.

But the problem I am having is outside the (document).ready(), when I have a function that calls the "loadTimeTrackersGrid()", it never reloads the flexigrid or makes a call to the file that contains the stored procedure.

My function(that I am trying to get to work) looks like this :

```
        function returnInvoicedItems() {
            loadTimeTrackersGrid();
        $('.menuBtn img').parent().children('ul').removeClass('menuShow');
    }
```

And this is how I am calling "returnInvoicedItems" function:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="returnInvoicedItems()">Non Invoiced Tracker</a></li>
```

Comment: It is not clear where you lose track of the call stack (in returnInvoicedItems ? loadTimeTrackersGrid ? flexigrid ? before that ?)
BTW, onclick="returnInvoicedItems(); return false;" should be better (and binding to the click event with jQuery should be even better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works like a gem:

```
 $('#viewTimeTrackersGrid').flexOptions({ url: 'Utilities/DataViewHandlers/ViewTimeTrackers.ashx?' + invoicedUrl + '&NonInvoiced=1' }).flexReload();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but I think I can see the problem. Your second function **returnInvoicedItems()** that calls **loadTimeTrackersGrid()**, it does have a jQuery code (in the line `$('.menuBtn img').parent().children('ul').removeClass('menuShow');`.  Now, if you have a jQuery call, don't you have to do make that call inside **$(document).ready()**?

Try to move **returnInvoicedItems()** inside **$(document).ready()** and see what happens.

Comment: it then gives me an "'target' is unvalid " error. But I've found a way around this. I got a solution. I just did this:$('#flexDiv').flexOptions({url: 'leURL.aspx?param=Foo&Foo=Bar’}).flexReload();